# Extremely simple validation function not working on form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am looking to create some extremely simple jQuery validation to check if an input field has a string or not.

To simplify my problem, I have created a validation function which invalidates the form with return false. Then, when the form is submitted, it runs a validation check before going onto some AJAX code.

As it stands, the AJAX code executes despite the validate_form() function returning false. Can anyone elaborate on this?

```
function validate_form() {
    return false;
}

$('form').submit(function() {

    // Run validation function
    validate_form();

    // If returns true, execute the following code...

})
```

Comment: `validate_form()` returns `false` and...nothing happens. Because it is literally set up to not do anything with that value.

Comment: You need to set it as value for example: var valid = validate_form(); and then if (valid) ....

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value:

```
return validate_form();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add parameter "e" to the function:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
```

And then try this when the validation returns false:

```
e.preventDefault(); // Cancel the submission
return false; // Exit the function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {

    // Run validation function
    if(!validate_form()){
        return false;
    }

    // If returns true, execute the following code...

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

The question seems incomplete

```
function validate_form(input_string){
    if(typeof input_string === 'string' || input_string instanceof String){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

$('form').submit(function(){
    var input_string = $("#yourinputID").val();
    var has_string = validate_form(input_string);

    if(has_string === true){
        //DO AJAX REQUEST
    }
    else{
        //DO NOT DO AJAX REQUEST
    }
});
```